# keyboard shortcut in the Command Palette is no longer working

Tags: sublimetext2

I've installed a Javascript formatter into ST2. For some reason, the keyboard shortcut is not working suddenly. When I search in my keymaps for `alt+ctrl+f` I don't see anything. How can I figure out why this shortcut is no longer doing anything? You can see the poorly formatted js in the screenshot. If I call the command via `Sh+Ctrl+P` it works fine. Does the Ctrl+Alt+F  on the right side in the screenshot indicate that that command is bound to that shortcut, or just that the package *thinks* that it is bound to that?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you try to use [FindKeyConflicts](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts).  This plugin will:

> Assist in finding key conflicts between various plugins. This plugin
>   will report back shortcut keys that are mapped to more than one
>   package. This does not guarantee that the listed plugins are
>   necessarily in conflict, as details, such as context, are ignored.
>   This is simply a tool to help assist what plugins may be conflicting.

Comment: That helped, thanks. Now that I've found the package that is conflicting (it's "Tag") how do I tell Tag to not use that shortcut?

Comment: Ahh, I got it, do a text search in /home/myacct/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Tag for `tag_indent` (the name of the conflicting command